# Adding custom email headers on iOS

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, email

I use **Mozilla Thunderbird** on OSX but I am considering getting an iPad. Thunderbird allows me to add any kind of custom email header. For me, this feature is essential.

Will I find an iOS app that can do the same?

Comment: Great question! @Gmacar, can you please tell me what answer you found? On my iPhone, I want to send emails via Amazon SES SMTP, and I want those emails to automatically use my main SES Configuration Set. So I need the app to allow me to add a custom header called `X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET` (according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-configuration-sets-in-email.html). Thanks.

Comment: I also added a bounty here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52805117/470749